# how to compare two infinite dimensional operators

Tags: abstract-algebra, infinite-matrices

Perturbation theory is crucial in quantum mechanics. I was wondering how to compare two operators in the case of two infinite-dimensional operator? Assume we have Hamiltonian $H_0$ and $V$. How formally I can show that $V \ll H_0$, such that I would expand in powers of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Even on infinite-dimensional operator a norm may be definied, therefore reducing the problem to a one-dimensional one, where $|V| \ll |H_0|$ is a valid assumption

Comment: Thanks, I also think there should be norm such that this is correct. However, what is the correct norm for comparing two (infinite-dimensional) operators?

Comment: Depends, I don't know your operators. If the spectrum of your operators are bounded(? I'm not sure about the correct englich term) you can use the largest eigenvector of an operator, respectively the sqaure root of the largest eigenvector of $T^{*}T$ for an operator $T$ ($T^{*}$ being the conjugate transposed of $T$)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it is sufficient to show all the eigenvalues of $S = V H_0^{-1}$ have absolute value less than the spectral radius of whatever power series you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reference possibly with one example on that matter?

Comment: I don't have a reference.  But think about solving the equation $(I-S)v = w$.  Then if the spectral radius of $S$ is less than 1, you can write $(I-S)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty S^k$.